# JSON outputs "Undefined" in Internet Explorer not other browsers

Tags: php, json, internet-explorer

----------This is testA.php-------------------------

```
[{"msgCD":"OK","msgSTR":"Hi"}]
```

----------This is testB.html-------------------------

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $('.submit').click(function(){
$.getJSON('testA.php',function(data){
    $.each(data,function(i,n){ 
        $('#message').append(n['msgCD']+'</br>');
    });
});
return false;});});
```

---

With Chrome and firefox, JSON outputs "HI" but IE, it doesn't work at all!!! OMG :(

Comment: What if you open `F12` in IE and see what happens?

Comment: also check your html markup may be it causinf problem ,check if all the html tags are properly formatted or not

Comment: stupid question but your php script is returning header mentioning json (instead of text/html)?
One other thing could be your call is being done BEFORE the html has finished loading, and #message does not yet exist in the dom, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

you have an object wrapped into an array, so you can't access the object directly:

```
var foo = [{"msgCD":"OK","msgSTR":"Hi"}]
foo.msgCD // undefined
foo[0].msgCD // "OK"
```

Edit:
I also suggest you to use the chrome console, just make a console.log(n) and you can browse through your object.